# How to connect a 4-pin OSC (crystal oscillator) to an IMU (BNO055) with only 2 pins dedicated to an external clock?

Tags: oscillator, clock, imu

I am using the BNO055 : 
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/BST_BNO055_DS000_12.pdf
and I can't seem to figure out how to connect a standard external oscillator clock to the chip. As suggested, I will use a 32 Khz oscillator.
There are generally 4 pins on the oscillators that I have researched: the VDD, GND, Output, and DNC. I get that the DNC is left floating, but how do I connect the remaining 3 pins to the 2 lines on the BNO055 (XOUT32 and XIN32).

Also, will it work if I just connect a standard clock to it rather than an oscillator?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BNO055 is designed to work with a crystal plus caps. That's what the XOUT32 pin is for, see page 100 of the datasheet.

You can also connect an external 32768Hz clock source to the XIN32 pin and leave the XOUT32 pin unused.

Comment: On Page 100, both the XOUT32 and XIN32 pins are used with a clock. And the figure specifies that it is connected to a crystal oscillator, not just a sole 2-pin crystal. I'm confused.

Comment: The diagram refers to an (external crystal) oscillator as opposed to the internal RC oscillator. Their description could be better- probably a translation. Janka's explanation is correct.

Comment: OHhh okay that makes more sense. So using a standard crystal should do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on your need for ppm error, an XO is preferred for newbies to an XTAL + 2 caps as you won't have to guess on stray capacitance induced frequency error.30ppm is pretty std. but 10ppm can be bought for $1.5 and just connect V+, 0V and output

Comment: The option with external clock source is incorrect, at least according to Bosch engineers

Answer (score 2):

This is delayed answer, but I feel it is important to avoid confusion.

BNO055 **cannot use logic level clock**, therefore external crystal is required, unless CLK_SEL bit is cleared (default state) to activate internal clock.

See a relevant answer in [this discussion](https://community.bosch-sensortec.com/t5/MEMS-sensors-forum/BNO055-32KHz-clock-externally-supplied/m-p/8357) at Bosch forum.

I would also recommend reading [this topic](https://community.bosch-sensortec.com/t5/MEMS-sensors-forum/BNO055-power-on-reset-issues/m-p/8641) for important changes in bypassing capacitor values, still missing from datasheet.

Comment: That's not really ultimately true.  Just because it does not accept a *logic level* clock input doesn't mean it cannot be made to accept any clock input in place of a crystal, whoever answered that query behind all the silly GDPR-abusing clickthrough was in a mood to be dismissive rather than very helpful.  What it means is that the external clock signal would need to be made to look more like the return from a crystal being operated by the internal oscillator.   Either knowledge of the sort of oscillator present on the chip or a bit of experimentation should do it.

Comment: One should then compare performance to make sure there has been no negative impact.  Granted, unless the oscillator to be used is something special or is also being used by something else, it's probably not worth it and a suitable crystal (vs oscillator) in 2 or 4 pin package should be selected.

Comment: Umm... basically what you are saying is that by spending a lot of time and effort one can _simulate crystal output_ instead of using actual $0.50 crystal. Just to prove Bosch engineer incorrect and myself a liar. Well, I guess you are correct on this one.

Comment: It's the kind of thing that's worth doing for a volume situation where you already have that clock for some other need.  And not when you're just trying to buy something to get a one-off to work, in that case the OP should have purchased a crystal not an oscillator.  But yes, simulating a crystal from a clock is exactly what the question was about, as unwise as that may be in the OP's case.

Comment: This is only worth doing if you can directly connect clock output pin from MCU (e.g. MCO in STM32 routed from LSE) to IMU clock input and be done with it. Everything else is rather wasting your time, considering $10 cost of BNO055 in _volume pricing_

Comment: Directly vs. via 1-3 SMD passives?  that's a silly distinction.  I'd agree it's not worth it for the OP.  And maybe the real answer is to choose a different IMU.